# limit hammer.js pan to specific directions

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

There's a way to limit the pan to two or three specific directions?
Like **down + right** or **both horizontal + up**?
(Hopefully using `Hammer.Pan` options and not the event listener)

Something like:

```
var hammerMan = new Hammer.Manager(DOMel);
hammerMan.add(new Hammer.Pan({
    direction: [Hammer.DIRECTION_DOWN, Hammer.DIRECTION_RIGHT]
}));
```

If not what's the best solution using the listener?

Answer (score 1):

Direction does not seem to take an array, but you can use `Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL` or `Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL`.

Comment: I know, I was thinking about other combinations of directions like two on different axis or maybe three directions.